# iOS - Should A Hidden UIImageView Of A UITableViewCell NOT Have An Assigned Image Until It's Visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory-management, uiimageview

I have `UITableViewController` where in its `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, if a certain condition is true about the `UITableViewCell`, I make its `UIImageView` visible. In my storyboard, I already have the `UIImageView` with an assigned image and hidden by default.

My question is this. Is it better, in terms of limiting my app's memory usage, to have the `UIImageView` NOT assigned to an image in the storyboard and just call this code when it needs to be displayed? :

```
myCell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
myCell.myImageView.hidden = NO;
```

I'm asking this because I'm wondering if the constant repetition of images will hog up too much memory even though they're hidden, and if it's better to ONLY assign an image when the `UIImageView`'s `hidden` attribute is about to be set to NO (to make it visible).

Comment: UIImage imageNamed: will cache images. If you don't want to cache images then you should use UIImage initWithImage. In terms of memory usage, it really depends on different factors such as, the size of the image, whether the image will be shown on many cells, or if a different image will be shown on each cell, etc. You should try to find a balance between memory usage and performance instead of just memory usage. Remember that if the image is constantly allocated in and deallocated from memory you will eventually see a loss in performance.

Comment: It's the same image on each cell. So does that mean I should stick with [UIImage imageNamed: blah]?

Comment: Since it's the same image on each cell I would say yes. In turn, your memory will only increase by the size of the image in memory once and you won't lose performance because the image is cached. I wouldn't even worry about hiding the image either because the entire cell will not be rendered until willDisplayCell: is called and that just adds extra logic to determine if you need to show or hide the image.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageNamed:` caches the image and is dumped when your app reaches a memory warning.

If the same key (@"myImage.png") is used in multiple places it reads from the same memory space and does not create multiple instances of the bitmap.

Memory issues with images crop up mostly when you're holding onto lots of large images strongly. There's many strategies, like using SDWebImage and letting that handle your image cache.

As always, resize your images as best you can to the size of the device that's viewing it, implement sensible caches and don't worry about memory so much!

You can check if your memory is being eaten up with the memory chart under the "Debug Navigator" (command - 6) and just scroll to see how your memory is being used.